# Why FIRST_VALUE() is not working properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I am running a query using `FIRST_VALUE()` window function in SQL. I am not getting the correct results.

The table is in the following format:

```
ID             DATE
1              2020-01-01
1              2020-01-02
1              NULL
2              2020-03-03   
2              2020-05-06
3              2020-06-07
3              2020-05-12
```

What I want to do is get the first oldest date for each **ID**. The current query I am using is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                FIRST_VALUE(date) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) as oldest_date
FROM tableX
```

**Note:** The dates can be **NULL**.

**P.S.** I have tried this with self-join and it works.

Thanks

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have lots of data, so it gives me random dates instead of the oldest date.

Comment: Please show us the results that you want for this sample data.

Comment: Your query works as coded producing 1 row per id with the first date. You need to clarify what you want by publishing desired output from sample data,

Comment: @P.Salmon let's say for ```id = 1``` I want 2020-01-01, for ```id = 2```, I want 2020-03-03.

Comment: @Uzair . . . That is a simple aggregation query.

Comment: If you want your query to exclude nulls then filter out the nulls with a where clause but as suggested by others a simple aggregation function seems appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right. But it does not give me correct results on my data.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `distinct` and window functions, which makes it quite unclear which result you actually want.

It you want one row per `id`, with the oldest non-`null` `date`, then use aggregation:

```
select id, min(date) oldest_date
from tableX
group by id
```

If you want as many rows as there are in the table, along with the oldest-date amongst rows sharing the same `id`, then I would recommend a window `min()`:

```
select t.*, min(date) over(partition by id) oldest_date
from tableX t
```

Comment: @P.Salmon: I am suspicious about `null` values with `first_value(date)` and `order by date`. It seems like OP wants to ignore `null`s, which `min()` just does.

Comment: It still does not work on my data. Only the self join solution is working,

Comment: @Uzair: not working is not precise about the problem. You are also yet to show the results that you want. Please provide that information by editing your question, so we can understand better, and possibly adapt the answer.

Comment: if I do not use ```DISTINCT``` with window function, it will not give me one row per id. That's why I am using ```DISTINCT```.

Comment: @Uzair: if you want one row per `id`, use the first query in my answer.

Comment: the required results are added in the above comments.

Comment: @uzair I disagree so you are going to tell us why/in what way it does not gve the correct result.

Comment: @Uzair . . . The required results should be in the *question*!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the `NULL` dates then add another sorting level:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
       FIRST_VALUE(date) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date IS NULL, date ASC) as oldest_date
FROM tableX
```

This will still return `NULL` if for an id there are not any non null dates.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vyv9A1LXWvt8nhSsnoQXM2/1).
Results:

```
| id  | oldest_date |
| --- | ----------- |
| 1   | 2020-01-01  |
| 2   | 2020-03-03  |
| 3   | 2020-05-12  |
```